# Feedback loop and Impulse Functions. How to find the response?

Tags: convolution, signal-processing, linear-control

[image]

This is my system. We know that h<sub>1</sub>(t) = δ(t-1) and h<sub>2</sub>(t) = δ(t+1).

Now my problem is how to find y(t). I know that the exit of the adder will give us

y<sub>1</sub>{t} = x(t) - h<sub>2</sub>(t) correct?

That means that y(t) = h<sub>1</sub> * y<sub>1</sub>{t} = δ(t-1)*x(t) - δ(t+1)*δ(t-1) = x(t-1) - δ(t).

However, I don't seem to understand how to draw the unit step response of y(t).

Comment: It tends to be a lot easier to do this in the s domain. That way all those convolutions become multiplications

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the LaPlace domain even though I know about it and it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up equations for a feedback loop, I usually start at the output and follow the path around once to see what happens to it.

If I start at $y(t)$, I go through the bottom block and get $y(t)*\delta(t+1)$, which yields $y(t+1)$.

Then I get to the summation block, and out pops $x(t)-y(t+1)$.

This signal then goes through the top block, becoming $\left[x(t)-y(t+1)\right]*\delta(t-1)=x(t-1)-y(t)$.

The signal that pops out of the top block *is* the output $y(t)$, so we can set up the equation:

$y(t)=x(t-1)-y(t)$.

Solving for y(t) gives: $y(t)=\frac{1}{2}x(t-1)$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense actually. My question is, how can we plot the step response of y(t) if we don't know what x(t-1) is?

Comment: the step response is what the output is if the input is a step. In other words, if $x(t)=u(t)$, what is $y(t)$?

Comment: Oh my. It was that simple? Thanks for this, my book didn't mention this at all!

Why is y(t+1)*δ(t-1) = y(t)? Shouldn't it be y(t-1)?

Comment: It's $y((t-1)+1)$, which is just $y(t)$

Comment: I assumed that but again this textbook I was given does not mention these properties at all. The two I knew of are x(t) ∗ δ(t-a) = x(t-a) and that δ(t-a) ∗ δ(t+a) = δ(t)

Comment: You can take that property to mean "convolving $x(t)$ with $\delta(t-t_0)$ makes you replace all the t's with $t-t_0$"

Comment: Got it, that's very useful to know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've got another question if you don't mind. If we have δ(t-2) ∗ -δ(t+1) our result is -δ(t+1) correct? Because only at t=-1, both functions are non-zero.

Comment: Applying the time shift rule would get you $\delta(t-2)*\delta(t+1)=\delta((t+1)-2)=\delta(t-1)$

Comment: Hmm I see. Well time to do some more reading on the shifting rule.